# Not able to clone repo from GitHub

Tags: git, github

I'm havin issues trying to clone a repo from GitHub.

It is giving the following error:

fatal: could not create work tree dir 'rando_repo': No such file or directory

What is going on? I've done this countless times before with no problem.

I've checked the permissions - thats all fine. 
The repo has a read-me file in it. 
I've tried both cmd and GitHub desktop - same error.

Comment: Sorry, my previous answer seems to be for a different issue.  What is the full path of your current working directory?

Comment: No worries. Well I'm looking to create my env on the desktop, so the path would be 'c:\Users\Troels Jensen\Desktop\rando-repo'. But it won't allow me to do so. But I've tried cloning it to 'c:\'. This appears to work fine - why? I don't think it's the length of my path so it must be the permissions. But I've checked that, and it says my current user has full permissions..